# How to get timezone information on sqlserver 2008 shared server

Tags: sql-server-2008, timezone

How to get timezone information on sqlserver 2008 . I am using go daddy shared server.

this statement is not execute due to permission problem in shared server.

exec master.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation',
'TimeZoneKeyName',@TZName OUT
select @TZName

Comment: Please just contact their support team. You will know your timezone information. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no other way to get the server's time zone, but you should not have any reason to do that.  If you've designed your application correctly, you should not be relying on local date and time at all.  Use UTC for all server-based clock operations.  If you need to convert to other time zones, you should be doing that in your application logic, not in your database.

Think about it this way, how do you even know where GoDaddy is hosting these servers?  How do you know they won't move them?  How do you know they aren't just set to the UTC time zone anyway - since that's usually the recommendation for servers?